# How to make it so only a div with a certain tag goes to a random location on program start, HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a website and I have a div with an id. I am using this code to get a certain id div to move randomly. I have tried many things and it has not worked. Code:

```
 // collect all the divs
 var divs = document.getElementsById('ad');
    // get window width and height
    var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var winHeight = window.innerHeight;

    // i stands for "index". you could also call this banana or haircut. it's a variable
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {

  // shortcut! the current div in the list
    var thisDiv = divs[i];

  // get random numbers for each element
    randomTop = getRandomNumber(0, winHeight);
    randomLeft = getRandomNumber(0, winWidth);

  // update top and left position
    thisDiv.style.top = randomTop + "px";
    thisDiv.style.left = randomLeft + "px";

}

// function that returns a random number between a min and max
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {

  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

}
```

I found It online and I don't think it works because my edit: Changing the `getElementsByType('div')` to `getElementsById('ad')`. "ad" is the id I used. Any idea how to get this to work? I need an answer soon because this is a school project.

I tried that code and I expected it to move my ad div to a random location every time the program was run.

Comment: Can you add your HTML to the question too?  When you say "Ad is the tag", are you using `<ad>something like this</ad>` or `<div id="ad">or like this</div>`?

Comment: Please go read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: `getElementsById` is not a thing (same as `getElementsByType` isn't, you probably meant `getElementsByTagName` there?) - it's singular, not plural, because IDs need to be unique to begin with. And since getElementById returns a single element only, and not a node list, the _loop_ over the result now doesn't make sense any more, you would have to work directly with that one single element instead.

Comment: @DigitalDan I am sorry for not clarifying, I am using <div id="ad">

Comment: @CBroe I will be sure to check that out, thanks, I will also try replacing trying byTagName.

Comment: Please see [ask] and  take the [tour]. You were asked to clarify your question with more detail, not drop tidbits down here in comments.

Comment: @Codeknight999 thanks for clarifying that you're using `<div id="ad">`.  Please add the HTML you're using to your question.  That will help people understand more about what you've tried; it will improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 0):

As you only want to position a single `<div>` you need to change your code to work with just one result instead of many.  You've tried to do that by using `getElementsById` but that isn't a valid function (in your browser you can use F12 to see the console / dev tools, where it will show an error).  Change it to `getElementById` to fix it (note I removed the "s").

As this is a school project, I won't write the code for you, but I'll give you some further hints:

- You won't need a `for` loop because you're only trying to change the position of the single `<div>`
- Your `<div id="ad">` may need the style `position: absolute;` for the new `top` and `left` values to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to take note of:

getElementsById doesn't exist. To get an element by ID you can use querySelector or getElementById.

Both of those will return a single element so there is no need for a loop.

Also #ad will need to be positioned absolutely.

Also, if you are getting the screen's width and height, I would recommend subtracting the div's width and height from the screen's width and height. That way your div won't go off the edge of the screen.

For testing purposes, I added a click button so you can keep clicking it to see the div move around. But you don't need that part.

```js
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

const thisDiv = document.querySelector('#ad');
const winWidth = window.innerWidth;
const winHeight = window.innerHeight;

document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  const randomTop = getRandomNumber(0, winHeight - thisDiv.scrollHeight);
  const randomLeft = getRandomNumber(0, winWidth - thisDiv.scrollWidth);

  thisDiv.style.top = randomTop + "px";
  thisDiv.style.left = randomLeft + "px";
});
```

```css
#ad {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Move Ad</button>
<div id="ad">Ad</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for the late reply.